# Getting a scale factor of a Bitmap after rotating it with a matrix

Tags: android, graphics

I've got the following problem which I tried to solve the whole day.
I load a Bitmap picture with his corresponding height and width into an ImageView.
Then I use a matrix for moving,scaling and rotating the image.
For scaling I'm using the postScale method.
For moving I'm using the postTranslate method. 
Only for Rotating I'm using the preRotate method.
Now I need to get the factor I scaled the image with, because I later need this factor in another program.

Using the MSCALE_X and MSCALE_Y values of the matrix only fits until I did no rotation. If I rotated the image, the scale values don't fit anymore (because the matrix was multiplied with the formula which is shown in the api).

Now my Question is: 
How can I still get the scale factor of the image after rotating it?

For the rotation factor (degrees) it is simple, because I store it within an extra variable which is icremented/decremented while rotating. 
But for the scale factor it does not work, because if I first scale an image down to 50% and then rescale it up to 150% then I scaled it with a factor of 3 but the original scaling factor is only 1.5).

Another example is. Even if I did not rescale the picture it even changes its scaling factor if I rotate it.

//Edit:
Finally I solved the problem on my own :) (doing a bit math and then I figured something interesting (or lets say obvious) out).

Here my solution:
I figured out that the values MSCALE_X and MSCALE_Y are calculated by using the cosinus function (yeah the basic math...). (Using 0° rotation leads to the correct scalingWidth and scalingHeight within X and Y). (90 and 270° results in a scalingWidth/Height of 0 and 180° results in a scalingWidth/Height multiplied by -1).

This leads me to the idea to write the following function:
This function saves the current matrix within a new matrix. Then it rotates the new matrix to the startstate (0°). Now we can read the non violated values MSCALE_X and MSCALE_Y in our matrix (which are the correct scaling factors now)

Comment: Hi @Vion can you show us some of your code where you implemented the new matrix. Thanks . I have same problem with you.

Comment: Hi @Vion can you show us some of your code where you implemented the new matrix. Thanks . I have same problem with you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  This is a simple way and the logic is sound (in my mind).

For: `xScale==yScale`

```
float scale = matrix.mapRadius(1f) - matrix.mapRadius(0f);
```

For: `xScale != yScale`

```
float[] points={0f,0f,1f,1f};
matrix.mapPoints(points);
float scaleX=points[2]-points[0];
float scaleY=points[3]-points[1];
```

If you are not translating, you may be able to get away with just with 1f vector/point.  I've tested the `xScale==yScale` (mapRadius) variant and it seems to work.

Comment: The only remark. Scale should be an absolute value. In some angle cases diff may give negative value which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an app I'm writing.  I couldn't see an obvious an simple solution so I just created a RectF object that had the same initial coords of the bitmap.  Then, everytime I adjusted the matrix, I'd apply the transformation to the RectF as well (using Matrix.mapRect() ).  This worked perfectly for me. It also allowed me to keep track of the absolute position of the edges of the bitmap.

Comment: Hi @coverdriven, can you give me a code. I had the same problem as yours. Its not working after rotating my bitmap using matrix. Thanks